# cleos on wax get info eror [Failed with error: Parse Error (4) Unexpected char '101' in "error"]

Tags: blockchain

1. When I -> cleos get info | it return: {
   "server_version": "a48fa1d9",
   "chain_id": "cf057bbfb72640471fd910bcb67639c22df9f92470936cddc1ade0e2f2e7dc4f",
   "head_block_num": 85,
   "last_irreversible_block_num": 84,
   "last_irreversible_block_id": "000000542a41f5672077709d84ab2514867b3a19c215ffd79a0654841cce4c6d",
   "head_block_id": "0000005581138e1662b53fab496d1616103c21f4b322e132eeacc9eb96b29740",
   "head_block_time": "2021-05-10T15:39:59.000",
   "head_block_producer": "eosio",
   "virtual_block_cpu_limit": 217493,
   "virtual_block_net_limit": 1140464,
   "block_cpu_limit": 200000,
   "block_net_limit": 1048576,
   "server_version_string": "v2.0.5wax01",
   "fork_db_head_block_num": 85,
   "fork_db_head_block_id": "0000005581138e1662b53fab496d1616103c21f4b322e132eeacc9eb96b29740",
   "server_full_version_string": "v2.0.5wax01-a48fa1d9fb676f3b41b6c2e7d1682067a5024630"
   }
2. When I -> cleos -u https://testnet.waxsweden.org get info | it return: {
   "server_version": "b5344cde",
   "chain_id": "f16b1833c747c43682f4386fca9cbb327929334a762755ebec17f6f23c9b8a12",
   "head_block_num": 89637852,
   "last_irreversible_block_num": 89637524,
   "last_irreversible_block_id": "0557c294756fea8e87c85838ca5e9cd535d7e333187987cc4cb1f669fed558ee",
   "head_block_id": "0557c3dc62b1d5377e30928fede5cab89b022a68ea3748ee7924be1ecfe0a009",
   "head_block_time": "2021-05-10T15:41:13.500",
   "head_block_producer": "eoseouldotio",
   "virtual_block_cpu_limit": 200000000,
   "virtual_block_net_limit": 1048576000,
   "block_cpu_limit": 199900,
   "block_net_limit": 1048576,
   "server_version_string": "v2.0.12wax01",
   "fork_db_head_block_num": 89637852,
   "fork_db_head_block_id": "0557c3dc62b1d5377e30928fede5cab89b022a68ea3748ee7924be1ecfe0a009",
   "server_full_version_string": "v2.0.12wax01-b5344cde06837726fef9e384fcedc207dcf6b160"
   }
3. But When I -> cleos -u https://chain.wax.io get info | it return error: error 2021-05-10T15:42:27.953 cleos     main.cpp:4013                 main                 ] Failed with error: Parse Error (4)
   Unexpected char '101' in "error"

---

Why?. any bro help me. pls

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try another endpoint, for example try https://wax.greymass.com instead of https://chain.wax.io, this should resolve your problem.

Comment: While this "works", doesn't really explain the error, especially because https://chain.wax.io/ resolves and has json.

Comment: chain.wax.io has hotlink protection enabled since its used for WAX's first-party products, other sites trying to use the endpoint will probably get a Cloudflare error page.

Comment: You gotta love it when the quickstart tutorial points you to something that causes and error.  With not explanation.  Thank you for this workaround.

Comment: @durbnpoisn It did used to work, but that endpoint was made less public since block producers run them now. The dev docs are maintained on github now, there is a discussion of how to update the docs. Should it show just one endpoint, or show all of the options?

Best practice is to use many endpoints to avoid issues with downtimes, what's the point of a decentralized blockchain if every project uses the same endpoint?